# Can't format internal (USB) drive because of Read-Only

Tags: macos, disk-utility, usb, disk-format

I have a macbook (running MacOS Catalina) connected to a HP 3005pr 3.0 Port Replicator.
This port replicator has a internal USB disk, I want to format this disk but am not able because it is Read-Only (see the diskutil below):

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):   
#:  TYPE NAME                SIZE.       IDENTIFIER
0:  FDisk_partition_scheme   *126.4 MB   disk2
1:  Windows_FAT_16 HP Dock    126.3 MB   disk2s1
```

When I type in '**diskutil info /dev/disk2s1**' I get this info:

```
Device Identifier:         disk2s1
   Device Node:               /dev/disk2s1
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk2

   Volume Name:               HP Dock
   Mounted:                   No

   Partition Type:            Windows_FAT_16
   File System Personality:   MS-DOS FAT16
   Type (Bundle):             msdos
   Name (User Visible):       MS-DOS (FAT16)

   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  USB
   SMART Status:              Not Supported
   Volume UUID:               6BD6C793-C86B-34D2-9BBC-1ACBD79E8FA0
   Partition Offset:          32256 Bytes (63 512-Byte-Device-Blocks)

   Disk Size:                 126.3 MB (126321152 Bytes) (exactly 246721 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

   Volume Total Space:        0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:         0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)

   Read-Only Media:           Yes
   Read-Only Volume:          Not applicable (not mounted)

   Device Location:           External
   Removable Media:           Removable
   Media Removal:             Software-Activated

   Solid State:               Info not available
```

When i try to format this disk whit the command '**diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 HP-USB /dev/disk2**'

```
Started erase on disk2
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Error: -69877: Couldn't open device
```

Any ideas howto switch off the Read-Only setting and format this disk?

Comment: HP don't claim any Mac compatibility at all on their site for this product. You may need to speak to them about it - https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-usb-3.0-3005pr-port-replicator/5256708/model/5256709

Comment: True, but the chipset in the HP 3005pr is from Displaylink. When you go to https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/macos you can use these. And also my question is not related to the port replicator but howto change the read-only setting of the disk.

Comment: A USB to SATA bridge (what connects the internal drive of this replicator to the USB) has nothing to do with DisplayLink.  Did you contact HP support to see if these are compatible with macOS?

Comment: That error, however, is indicative of a drive or enclosure problem, and not a Read Only issue - see the link.  We can reopen if we can find some evidence of functionality and compatibility.